# Using glob() to find directories after a point in time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a directory system set up like below:

```
root
├── logs
│   ├── 20151109
│   │   ├── default.log
│   ├── 20151110
│   │   ├── default.log
│   ├── 20151111
│   │   ├── default.log
```

These logs are generated once per day and go back about seven months, but I only want the past week's log files. So if today were 2015-11-12 (November 12, 2015), I want the log files in the folders from "20151105" (November 5) through "20151111" (November 11).

How do I tell `glob.glob()` to only return the results of those specific files? I tried just running `glob.glob("logs/*/default.log")` and grabbing the last 7 entries in the generated list, but it appears that `glob()` doesn't return the folder results in any particular order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not sorting the results:

```
sorted(glob.glob("logs/*/default.log"))[-7:]
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[-7:]` (to get the last 7, vs. `[:-7]` which gets all _but_ the last 7)?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can sort the files from the desired folder by date:

```
import glob
import os

files = glob.glob("*cycle*.log")
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
print("\n".join(files))
```

Or you can try:

```
import glob
import os
import time

searchedfile = glob.glob("*.log")
files = sorted( searchedfile, key = lambda file: os.path.getctime(file))

for file in files:
 print("{} - {}".format(file, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file))) )
```

Also note that this uses creation time, if you want to use modification time, the function used must be `getmtime`.

Comment: While useful in other cases, the creation/modification dates may not correspond to the "logical" folder dates; user activity could change them (and it requires `stat`-ing all the files, where string based sorts only need the names pulled directly from the directory info in one go-round).

Comment: Also, side-note: You didn't need a `lambda` (people overuse them when they don't understand the concept of callback functions). `os.path.getctime` is already a perfectly appropriate `key` callback function; `sorted(searchedfile, key=os.path.getctime)` (also fixing spacing to match PEP8 while I was at it) is shorter and faster (executes less Python byte code during sorting, doesn't create unnecessary function objects).

Comment: While this is useful, I can't depend on the creation/modification times of the file, due to the way the files system is used. Thanks though!